# Comment traduire « boutique X services » ?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, anglais, informatique

Je tombe sur des sociétés qui offrent des « *[boutique](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/boutique#Noun) X services* », par exemple en technologies de l'information. C'est le nom employé comme adjectif appliqué au domaine qui vient qualifier le type de services offerts et *Wiktionary* parle de « Any company specializing in bespoke or custom-made products or services for clientele in a niche market ». [Termium](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=BOUTIQUE&index=enw&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) a des idées, celle de *niche*, celle de ce qui est *personnalisé*, ce qui est *spécialisé*, le *guichet*.

Comment traduit-on généralement ce *boutique*-là et avec TI(*IT*) ou autrement, qualifiant ces services qu'offrent ces sociétés et pourquoi ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boutique_firm Sur mesure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Sur mesure*. [[Lambie](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/49542/comment-traduire-boutique-x-services#comment101560_49542), en commentaires.]

Comment: @Lambie C'est possible d'aller plus loin. Par exemple dans une autre réponse tu pourrais appliquer cet élément de réponse à _(firm offering) boutique IT services (firm)_. On pourrait aussi brièvement expliquer la connotation de _boutique_ et dire s'il y a un élément de prestige associé à cet emprunt-là et pourquoi _sur mesure_ cadrerait avec ces idées-là. Incidemment par curiosité, comment aurais-tu réagi à _de type boutique_.

Comment: de type boutique pourrait expliquer mais ne traduis pas.

Comment: @Lambie Pour moi ça n'explique pas vraiment, simplement si on l'oppose à grande-surface que je comprends a contrario qu'on parlerait d'un service plus personnalisé, et éventuellement je penserais peut-être à _sur mesure_ justement mais je ne trouve pas ça clair au premier coup d’œil. C'est parce que je trouve boutique un peu vieillot en français, et je suis certain qu'en informatique quand ils emploient boutique ce n'est vraiment pas le genre de connotation qu'ils désirent avoir. Donc dans mon esprit le boutique en anglais et celle en français ce sont des _watertight compartments_.

Comment: @Ti-culTi-caille Ce *boutique* me fait penser à *concierge*.

Comment: @Ti-culTi-caille "boutique services" n'est pas lié à l'informatique mais au type de service, sur mesure, personnalisés et comme dans une boutique, on s'occupe de vous plus que dans une grande surface, p.ex.

Comment: @jlliagre Oui, ça marcherait en Europe. Mais chez moi le concierge c'est la personne qui sort les poubelles de l'immeuble etc., c'est pas prestigieux ou associée à l’hôtellerie haut de gamme, ni beaucoup au sens de surveillance ou à la personne attentionnée.

Comment: @Lambie Je n'ai jamais dit que c'était relié mais j'ai trouvé des exemples comme _boutique IT services_ et avec _firm_, _that's quite a mouthful_, et parfois l'aspect attributif semble appliqué autant à firm qu'aux types de services, et c'est possible, ça donne une PME offrant des services sur mesure. Je veux dire, quand les services offerts sont informatiques, il faut bien appliquer le sens sur cette détermination du service. C'est pour ça que la réponse est incomplète.

Comment: @Ti-culTi-caille Oui, la perception de concierge est la même ici. Concierge n'est pas du tout prestigieux ou associé à un service personnalisé de haut de gamme. Si j'ai fait le lien avec boutique, c'est que le *boutique* anglais semble apporter une connotation de haut de gamme comme le *concierge* anglais alors que le boutique français est neutre et concierge plutôt péjoratif. Les concierges parisiens ont beaucoup disparu car les propriétaires des immeubles ont préféré vendre leurs logements, vu la hausse du prix de l'immobilier.

Comment: @jlliagre Ah, ok, je ne connais pas le _concierge_ anglais, je n'ai pas entendu ça dans mon monde où j'ai pas les moyens de l'avoir entendu ahahaha. Oui, il y a le niveau d'attention, le sur mesure, l'agilité, le style, le contraire du gros, le _small_ (avec beaucoup d'expertise) _is beautiful_. Une forme d'élitisme structurello-corporativo-marketing. Sur ELU qqn. comme cerberus haït ça, il trouve que c'est du lingo de publicité. Ça semble donc récent et prétentieux pour certains.

Comment: @Ti-culTi-caille https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concierge

Comment: @jlliagre Ah, ok, comme à l'hôtel dans John Wick !